# fread unexpected behaviour when reading N bytes

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I'm trying to read a binary file four bytes at a time. I came up with this code which produces the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char instr[4];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("tests", "rb");

    while( fread(instr, 1, 4, fp) != 0 ) {
        printf("%td", strlen(instr));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin_files
44444
```

This modified version on the other hand produces an output I can't explain:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    char instr[4];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("tests", "rb");

    printf("%d\n", i);

    while( fread(instr, 1, 4, fp) != 0 ) {
        printf("%td", strlen(instr));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin_files
10
55555
```

Why is it now reading 5 bytes at a time?

NB: I'm on a Macbook which is why I'm using `%td` instead of `%d` like my tutorial for printing the string length.

Comment: What is your input? Who is guaranteeing the `instr` will be null-terminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen` requires a pointer to a string as parameter but `fread` does not null terminate its buffer. Use the accumulated `fread` return value to get the size read.

Moreover use `%zu` conversion specification to print a `size_t` value (the type of the value returned by `strlen`). `%tu` is used for `ptrdiff_t` type.

Answer (score 1):

`fread` does not add the `NUL` character (`'\0'`) at the end of your array. What you have is not a string .

And `strlen` requires an argument as string, the length of a string is determined by the terminating `NUL` character. Therefore such behaviour.

You can manually add a `NUL` character in your array to make it a string.

Also `strlen` returns a length of type `size_t`, so use the `%zu` specifier to print it.